# update field in subarray of an mongocollection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

i have the following data-structure:

```
{
  answers: [
    {
      text: 'text',
      owner: 'owner',
      timestamp: timestamp,
      comments: [
        {
          text: 'text',
          timestamp: timestamp,
          owner: 'owner'
        }
      ]
    }       
  ]
}
```

and here is my update-command:

```
return Questions.update({
        _id: id,
        'answers.timestamp': answerTimestamp,
        'answers.comments.timestamp': commentTimestamp,
        'answers.comments.owner': this.userId
      }, {
        $set: {
          'answers.$.comments.$.text': text
        }
      });
```

...and here is the error:

```
Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.
```

The code runs server-side! Can someone help?

Comment: You cant use $ twicein 'answers.$.comments.$.text'. I know this is not gonna solve your problem but this query works 'answers.$.comments.0.text'

Comment: Ok, but what is the common workaround?

Comment: there is but not really great

Comment: you have to use Questions.find(..).forEach(function(item) { // search you conditions here via javascript code })

Comment: thx, first fetching, then updating :)

Comment: not perfect but the only way